# Angular show cached data and update the new data if needed data in background

Tags: angular

I'm developing an Angular app that handles a massive amount of data from the server.
So every API call can take up to 5 seconds and there are pages we have few API calls.

What I want to achieve is to save the data in cache for every page I'm visiting and if I navigate to the page again I will see the cached data immediately, call API to get new data and refresh only the component that their model has changed.

Now API calls are being done from `ngOnInit` method and the app show spinner until the results are shown.

Is there any best practice to achieve that behavior in Angular, other than saving the json in local-storage or something similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR;** google for "caching technics with RxJS"

**The bigger answer:**

There are several options:

- save data to `localStorage`/`sessionStorage` if you need it to be persistent
- save it in service as plain data(just some variable)
- simulate state with something like `BehaviorSubject` and retrieve it latest value([article](https://medium.com/@rmcavin/my-favorite-state-management-technique-in-angular-rxjs-behavior-subjects-49f18daa31a7) for example)
- using [caching with RxJS](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html)
- use storage like [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/), if you have one

...and many more depending on what you want, and how the code is constructed.

If I was you - I would pick the variant with `BehaviorSubject` as initial if it is a simple application and don't have a huge state and it's management.

Comment: Caching with RxJS is really a wonderful article ! thank you a lot this helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

Question is unfocused but I'll bite.

**Ways of saving data in increasing complexity are**:

- using a collection service with your own interface of methods (addWidget, removeWidget etc.) that injects the api service
- using a caching service and http interceptor [Angular - HttpClient -Caching](https://angular.io/guide/http#caching)
- using a rxjs + facade (there's a talk from ng-conf on push based services)
- using `ngrx` (I recommend `@ngrx/data` if you have control over the api design and `@ngrx/entity` otherwise)

These are all "online" so that app refresh loses the data and refresh api calls would be needed (which isn't necessarily a bad thing).

**Good principles and rules of thumb**:

- break your api response into entities (e.g. using normalizr) so that your front end only has to update state is one place only
- use interfaces liberally for both the api response, broken down entity model and view models for the components which combines state (several entities)
- use container/component pattern - container to handle getting, combining the data or dispatching state changes and component only knows have to recieve data and notify container of events
- if using `ngrx` a good pattern is API → normalizr → entities → store